# Make a view scrollable in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I am making a tabbar-based iPhone application. In one of the tab I need the scrollable view. How can I make it?

Comment: You can use Scroll view.

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a UIScrollView to the tab view. Some resources to get you started:

1. [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) in the Apple documentation
2. [UIScrollView tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3393-uiscrollview-tutorial.html)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIScrollView to make stuff scrollable.

Comment: It would help then if you posted the exact problem your having with the UIScrollView, i'm guessing you haven't called the 'setContentSize' method on your scroll view to actually make it scrollable